# Return value from Django view to JS function

Tags: python, javascript, geodjango

I am building a webmap using GeoDjango, Leaflet and PostGIS. I am trying to write a function that returns a raster value from a database when the user clicks on the map (i.e., via a JS alert, or other means). I have read a number of posts on SE but can't seem to get the code to work myself.

The relevant code is below... first, the JS functions:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    var lng = e.latlng.lng;
    var lat = e.latlng.lat;
    console.log("I clicked!");
    resp = updateLatLng(lat, lng);
    console.log('The response is: ', resp);
});

function updateLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var data = {'lat': lat, 'lng': lng, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'};
    $.post('{% url 'legend' %}', data);
    var response = '{{result}}';
    return response
};
```

The `legend` view in `views.py` is as follows:

```
def legend_view(request):

  lat = request.POST['lat']
  lon = request.POST['lng']

  query = "SELECT ST_Value(raster, ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4326), 4326)) FROM my_raster_layer;" % (lon, lat)

  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydb' user='postgres'")
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute(query)
  result = cur.fetchall()[0][0]

  print("\n\n++++++++++++\nInside the legend view\n")
  print("Lat: ", lat, "   Lon: ", lon)
  print("Value: ", result)
  print("++++++++++++\n\n")

  return HttpResponse(result)
```

When I click on the map, it successfully sends the lat and long values to `views.py`, as well as successfully queries the database. I can see this because it prints in the terminal I'm running the webmap from. However, it does not seem to be returning the value to the JS, as `result` is printing nothing.

Some other relevant SE items that I've followed, but can't get to work for my particular case:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445989/passing-python-data-to-javascript-via-django
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Django, but to my eyes it looks like your problem is with the concept of an AJAX call.

Using jQuery's `$.post` is an **asycnhronous** operation, so you can't work with it using a **synchonous** programming style (i.e. assigning the function's ouput to a variable).

Instead, you must supply a [callback function](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) which is exectued after the client recieves the server's response. Depending on how you want to display the data, you have a few different options.

#### Option 1

<s>The best way,</s>  if you don't need to use the value for other operations in JavaScript, is to drop the value into your HTML with jQuery.

#### Option 2

If you want to use `alert` you can, but it's bad UX and I wouldn't reccommend it.

#### Option 3

Finally, if you need to actually work with the variable you can initialize a variable on page load, then assign the new value to that variable in the callback. This is probably more complicated than you need.

#### Option 4

The NEW best option (because I was bored) is probably to just use the Leaflet popup.

With some help from the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
// Initialize variable for use later
var theValue;
var popup = L.popup();

function updateLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var data = {'lat': lat, 'lng': lng, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'};
    $.post('{% url 'legend' %}', data, function(resp) {
        // Option 1
        $("#raster-value").html("The value is: " + resp.result.value);            
        // Option 2
        alert("The value is: " + resp.result.value);
        // Option 3  -  Display the same way as Option 1, but you can
        //              do other stuff with it too.
        theValue = resp.result.value;
        $("#raster-value").html("The value is: " + theValue);
        // Option 4
        popup
          .setLatLng([lat, lng])
          .setContent('<pThe value is:<br />' + resp.result.value + '</p>')
          .openOn(map); // Obviously this assumes the map is initialized
    });
};
```

I would also suggest that you take a look at [this SE post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python) on returning AJAX responses from Django using JSON.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'm still unclear on how I would return that response, though. I just want to post that data upon clicking, and return a value from the database that I can then use within the JS script of my template. I've tried a variety of things in the callback function you suggest, but with no luck.

Comment: Can you post your template? Where are you actually trying to use the values? Does my function log something to your JS console?

Comment: The template is quite large, but the JS functions I posted above are the relevant script portion. The function you gave does log the value to the console with `console.log(resp.result);`. I see you updated your post with a not about asynchronous operations... how do I assign the value to a variable that I can use elsewhere in the JS script? Ultimately I want to build a popup on the map with the data returned from the database.

Comment: Updated to show how you can use this with jQuery's DOM manipulation. You'll probably want create something almost like a legend on the map which you can update every time the user clicks. If you're feelin' javascripty though, you can try implementing [leaflet's built in popups.](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#popup)

Comment: Cool -- thanks a ton. This gets me over the hurdle I hit. SE says I can't award the bounty for another 19 hrs. Ping me if I don't in a few days time. And yes -- I'm using Leaflet's built in popups but also want to do some backend raster processing using PostGIS's functions, hence the need for dynamic extraction of data.

Comment: Cool, added a leaflet example for you to follow as well. This is all untested so let me know if something doesn't work and you find a solution; I'll fix it in my answer.